# Vertically Aligning Text with Image in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Today's WordPress trauma...

Goal: using a three column layout, have an icon next to link text, followed by some descriptive text.

> 50pxICON (here's my link that should be centered vertically next to
>   the icon)
>
> Here's some text describing the destination

What I can't seem to do is get my link text vertically centered on the icon. I've tried wrapping it in a div, tried specifying the height of the div, etc... I'm sure it's something basic that I'm overlooking

Current code:

```
[col3]<div style="height:50px;"><img src="myimage">  <a href="mylink" class="link-text" vertical-align="middle">text</a></div>

Here's our description[/col3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways & approach, Try this approach and Hopefully, this will help.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="myimage" style="
   height: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;" />  
   <a href="mylink" class="link-text" 
      style="display: inline-block; 
      vertical-align: middle;">
    Your text
   </a>
</div>
```